# How do I pass a parameter to an <ant ../> call?

Tags: ant

I have a master build file which is calling other build.xml files of different projects.

One of my build file needs a command line argument for the  execution

```
ant -Denv=81 -buildfile build_war.xml
```

I wrote one task in master build.xml to call build_war.xml

```
<target name="buildDataExtractor">
  <ant antfile="..\SEFTooling\build_war.xml" inheritall="false" /> 
</target>
```

How do I pass the "-Denv=81" parameter so that build_war.xml will be executed correctly.

Comment: @ Amrin:   a property that has same name as task (env). Consider improving the name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try passing properties to the [ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html):

```
<ant antfile="..\SEFTooling\build_war.xml" inheritall="false">
  <property name="env" value="${env}"/>
</ant>
```

NOTE: in order for this to work properly, you will need to call your main build with `ant -Denv=81` or set a property in the main build.xml as such:

```
<property name="env" value="81"/>
```

Comment: Why pass the exact value, and not the reference to the variable? for example: value="${env}"

Comment: It appears to me from the question that there is no such variable.  If there is, your suggestion would work as well

Comment: It's available via -D when calling ant. From http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html : "You can also set properties on the command line. This can be done with the -Dproperty=value option, where property is the name of the property, and value is the value for that property."

Comment: You can easily verify this with a basic ant file. Just create a target that calls <echo message="cmdLine" />. And from the command line call you target with "ant -DcmdLine=HELLLOOOO".

Comment: @SpencerKormos Good idea. I've edited the answer to take in your comment.

Comment: I'd have done it myself, but I don't have enough rep yet. :-D